# Copy cell above if 2 criteria from separate columns are met

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for VBA to copy cell above (in column E) if cell in E is empty and AJ is anything other than empty. Currently this is copying the cell above but is not taking into account the AJ column. Fairly new to VBA and not sure where I am going wrong. Any input is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CopyFIN() 'copies FIN from account above if E is empty and AJ is anything other than empty

Dim lr As Long
Dim rcell As Range
Dim col As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
Set col = Range("E12:E" & lr)
Set col2 = Range("AJ12:AJ" & lr)

    For Each rcell In col2
        If rcell.Value <> "" Then
        End If
    Next

    For Each rcell In col
        If rcell.Value = "" Then
            rcell.Offset(-1, 0).Copy rcell
        End If
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Your first loop wasn't doing anything and your second was only checking column E.

```
Sub CopyFIN() 'copies FIN from account above if E is empty and AJ is anything other than empty

Dim lr As Long
Dim rcell As Range
Dim col As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
Set col = Range("E12:E" & lr)

For Each rcell In col
    If Len(rcell) = 0 And Len(Cells(rcell.Row, "AJ")) > 0 Then
        rcell.Offset(-1, 0).Copy rcell
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks so much! Now I just have to go figure out "Len" Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure. Checking Len(gth) equals zero is equivalent to checking if the cell is empty.